# CSS child selector: can't select rows direct children of table, excluding children of sub-table

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can't figure out why I can't achieve selecting rows that are direct children of a table (given that other sub-table are included in TD's of main table, I just want direct children rows, not rows of descendant tables).

Here the remaining structure after radical simplification (also see [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wn84hotm/1/)):

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>TR 1 - TD 1 </td>
            <td>TR 1 - TD 2 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TR 2 - TD 1</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table 2 - A </td>
                        <td>Table 2 - B </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table 2 - C</td>
                        <td>Table 2 - D</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I'm not able to select rows that are direct children of the main table:
- `body>table tr {background-color:lightgray;}` logically selects all rows of table and sub-table
- `body>table tr tr {color:blue;}` logically selects all rows of sub-table only
- **but** `body>table>tr {color:red;}` **doesn't select anything at all** (no red text to be seen)

What am I doing wrong? On the structure? On the selectors?
[->jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wn84hotm/1/)

Comment: Check in console and see if `<tbody>` is being inserted by the browser.

Comment: I had checked the structure through the "view source" in Firefox, didn't think the console would show me more... I'll remember this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `tbody` element may be automatically inserted when it is not in the markup (the side effect is that a `table > tr` selector could fail), so try to change last rule  with `body > table > tbody tr`.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/wn84hotm/2/

Comment: Actually it doesn't really work as I'd expect: `body > table > tbody > tr` gets selected, but the css properties also apply to TRs in sub-table (to anything descendant of TR in fact: http://jsfiddle.net/wn84hotm/4/)  -that's probably why it's called "cascaded"... I would have liked ONLY direct TR-children to be affected.

Comment: Sorry, it DOES work on my server. Just not on jsfiddle. Many thanks.